# Merge arrays if they contain one or more of the same value

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of arrays:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [8, 9], [9, 10]]
```

I would like to merge all arrays that contain one or more of the same value. So:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

I'm struggling to find a concise approach for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is correct:

```
def merge_em(a)
  return a if a.empty?
  rest = a.dup
  groups = []
  group = []
  while rest.any?
    group = rest.shift if group.empty?
    if i = rest.each_index.find { |i| (rest[i] & group).any? }
      group |= rest[i]
      rest.delete_at(i) 
      groups << group if rest.empty?
    else
      groups << group
      group = []
    end
  end
  groups
end

a = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [98, 99], [6, 7, 8], [8, 9], [9, 10]]
merge_em(a)
  #=> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [98, 99], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

How's this:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [98, 99], [6, 7, 8], [8, 9], [9, 10]]

b = [ a.shift ] # start with first sequence
a.each do |seq|
  match = nil
  b.each do |existing_sequence|
    match = existing_sequence if existing_sequence.any? {|x| seq.include? x }
  end
  if match
    seq.each {|x| match << x } # coalese matching fragment
  else
    b << seq # new fragment
  end
end

p b.map {|x| x.uniq }

# => [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [98, 99], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Comment: oops, first pass didn't handle out of order. I guess you have to check all the combinations. I think this re-orders the elements, but that shouldn't be too hard to fix.

Comment: Seems to work. I'm still getting some nils on what is a very large & complex dataset. But every simplified approach I try seems to work - must be a problem with my data.

Comment: If `a = [[100,9], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5], [98, 99], [6, 7, 8], [8, 9], [9, 10]]`, your code prints `[[100, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [98, 99], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]`.