# Merging arrays containing the same values

Tags: python, numpy

I need to get a high correlation group from the correlation coefficient matrix, keep one of them and exclude the other。But I don't know how to do it gracefully and efficiently.

Here's a similar answer, but hopefully it will be done using a vector-like matrix.：
[Merge arrays if they contain one or more of the same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314022/merge-arrays-if-they-contain-one-or-more-of-the-same-value)

For example:

```
a = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,1,0,1,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0,1,1],
              [0,1,0,1,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0,1,0],              
              [1,0,1,0,0,1]])
```

Diagonal:

```
(0,0),(1,1),(2,2)...(5,5)
```

Other:

```
(0,5),(1,3),(2,4),(2,5)
```

These three pairs because each other contains merged into a group of：

```
(0,2,4,5) = (0,5),(2,4),(2,5)
```

So ultimately I need the output:
(I will use the results to index other data and therefore decide to keep the largest index in each group)

```
out = [(0,2,4,5),(1,3)]
```

I think the simplest approach is to take a nested loop and iterate through all the elements multiple times. I would like to have a more concise and efficient way to achieve, thank you

This is a loop implementation, I'm sorry to write it hard to see：

```
a = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,1,0,1,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0,1,1],
              [0,1,0,1,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0,1,0],              
              [1,0,1,0,0,1]])

a[np.tril_indices(6, -1)]= 0     
a[np.diag_indices(6)]    = 0     
g = list(np.c_[np.where(a)])

p = {}; index = 1
while len(g)>0:
    x = g.pop(0)
    if not p:
        p[index] = list(x)
        for i,l in enumerate(g):
            if np.in1d(l,x[0]).any()|np.in1d(l,x[1]).any():
                n = list(g.pop(i))
                p[index].extend(n)
    else:
        T = False
        for key,v in p.items():
            if np.in1d(v,x[0]).any()|np.in1d(v,x[1]).any():
                v.extend(list(x))
                T = True
        if T==False:
            index += 1; p[index] = list(x)
            for i,l in enumerate(g):
                if np.in1d(l,x[0]).any()|np.in1d(l,x[1]).any():
                    n = list(g.pop(i))
                    p[index].extend(n)

for key,v in p.items():
    print key,np.unique(v)
```

out:

```
1 [0 2 4 5]
2 [1 3]
```

Comment: Please post the code for the simple solution using for loops.  Then we can try to improve it.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not clear to me what you're trying to do

Comment: @John Zwinck Okay, I've updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The central problem of merging / consolidating the pairs with common extrema can be solved using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52552560/a-list-of-identical-elements-in-the-merge-list/52554530#52554530).

Hence, the above code may be rewritten like:

```
a = np.array([[1,0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,1,0,1,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0,1,1],
              [0,1,0,1,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0,1,0],              
              [1,0,1,0,0,1]])

a[np.tril_indices(6, -1)]= 0     
a[np.diag_indices(6)]    = 0     
g = np.c_[np.where(a)].tolist()

def consolidate(items):
    items = [set(item.copy()) for item in items]
    for i, x in enumerate(items):
        for j, y in enumerate(items[i + 1:]):
            if x & y:
                items[i + j + 1] = x | y
                items[i] = None
    return [sorted(x) for x in items if x]

p = {i + 1: x for i, x in enumerate(sorted(consolidate(g)))}
```