# a list of identical elements in the merge list

Tags: python

I need to merge the list and have a function that can be implemented, but when the number of merges is very slow and unbearable, I wonder if there is a more efficient way

Consolidation conditions：Sub-lists contain identical numbers to each other Thank you

Simple Association:

```
[7,8,9] = [7,8]+[8,9]   #The same number 8
```

Cascade contains：

```
[1,2,3]   = [1,2,3]+[3,4] #The same number 3 
[3,4,5,6] = [3,4],[4,5,6] #The same number 4 
[1,2,3,4,5,6] = [1,2,3]+[3,4,5,6] #The same number 3
```

Function：

```
a =  [ [1,2,3],[4,5,6],[3,4],[7,8],[8,9],[6,12,13] ]
b = len(a)
for i in range(b):
    for j in range(b):
        x = list(set(a[i]+a[j]))
        y = len(a[j])+len(a[i])
        if i == j or a[i] == 0 or a[j] == 0:
            break
        elif len(x) < y:
            a[i] = x
            a[j] = [0]
            print a
print [i for i in a if i!= [0]]
```

result：

```
[[8, 9, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11]]
```

Above is an example where each sub-list in the actual calculation has a length of only 2,

```
a =  [[1,3],[5,6],[3,4],[7,8],[8,9],[12,13]]
```

I want to miss out more data, here is a simulation data.

```
a = np.random.rand(150,150)>0.99 
a[np.tril_indices(a.shape[1], -1)] = 0     
a[np.diag_indices(a.shape[1])]     = 0     
a = [list(x) for x in np.c_[np.where(a)]]

consolidate(a)
```

Comment: I dont quite understad what is the condition to merge the lists. Would you mind to explain?

Comment: Sub-lists contain identical numbers to each other Thank you

Comment: @weidong I am still not clear on what you want the conditions to be? Can you edit your question to add a general example on how the list transforms into a desired output?

Comment: @weidong your question would be so much easier to answer if you could provide one (or more) examples of a clear input and a clear desired output. On a different note, unless you have compelling reasons not to, you should use Python 3. If you must use Python 2, it might be a good idea to update your question / tag accordingly.

Comment: Can you assume that your inner lists contain no repetition? and that the overlap between any two given inner list is at most 1 number? What should happen for middle number overlaps (e.g. `[1, 2, 3]` and `[4, 3, 5]`)?

Comment: @norok2 Yes, the sub-list is actually the coordinates of the 2d matrix

Comment: @weidong I am sorry, is your code supposed to work? Because there are, to a minimum, clear indentation issues.

Comment: @ norok2 Sorry I have updated

Comment: Is the ordering important? Because if not, you can probably use sets instead.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you want to achieve here. Expected input/output would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your algorithm is close to optimal, except that the inner loop can be shortened because the intersection operation is symmetric, i.e. if you check that `(A, B)` intersect, there is no need to check for `(B, A)`.
This way you would go from `O(n²)` to `O(n * (n / 2))`.

However, I would rewrite the piece of code more cleanly and I would also avoid modifying the input.
Note also, that since `set`s do not guarantee ordering, it is a good idea to do some sorting before getting to list.

Here is my proposed code (**EDITED** to reduce the number of castings and sortings):

```
def consolidate(items):
    items = [set(item.copy()) for item in items]
    for i, x in enumerate(items):
        for j, y in enumerate(items[i + 1:]):
            if x & y:
                items[i + j + 1] = x | y
                items[i] = None
    return [sorted(x) for x in items if x]
```

Encapsulating your code in a function, I would get:

```
def consolidate_orig(a):
    a = [x.copy() for x in a]
    b = len(a)
    for i in range(b):
        for j in range(b):
            x = list(set(a[i]+a[j]))
            y = len(a[j])+len(a[i])
            if i == j or a[i] == 0 or a[j] == 0:
                break
            elif len(x) < y:
                a[i] = x
                a[j] = [0]
    return [i for i in a if i!= [0]]
```

This would allow us to do some clean micro-benchmarking (for completeness I have included also @zipa's `merge()`):

---

## EDIT:

@zipa's code is not properly encapsulated, here is an equivalent version with proper encapsulation:

```
def merge(iterable, base=None):
    if base is None:
        base = iterable
    merged = set([tuple(set(i).union(
        *[j for j in base if set(i).intersection(j)])) for i in iterable])
    if merged == iterable:
        return merged
    else:
        return merge(merged, base)
```

and updated timings:

```
in_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [3,4], [7,8], [8,9], [6,12,13]]
%timeit consolidate_orig(in_list)
# 17.9 µs ± 368 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit consolidate(in_list)
# 6.15 µs ± 30 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit merge(in_list)
# 53.6 µs ± 718 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

in_list = [[1, 3], [5, 6], [3, 4], [7, 8], [8, 9], [12, 13]]
%timeit consolidate_orig(in_list)
# 16.1 µs ± 159 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit consolidate(in_list)
# 5.87 µs ± 71.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit merge(in_list)
# 27 µs ± 701 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

Showing that, at least for this input, the proposed solution is consistently faster.
Since it is not too straightforward to generate large meaningful inputs, I'll leave to you to check that this is more efficient then your approach for the larger inputs you have in mind.

---

## EDIT

With larger, but probably meaningless inputs, the timings are still favorable for the proposed version:

```
in_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [3,4], [7,8], [8,9], [6,12,13]] * 300
%timeit consolidate_orig(in_list)
# 1.04 s ± 14.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit consolidate(in_list)
# 724 ms ± 7.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit merge(in_list)
# 1.04 s ± 7.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

in_list = [[1, 3], [5, 6], [3, 4], [7, 8], [8, 9], [12, 13]] * 300
%timeit consolidate_orig(in_list)
# 1.03 s ± 18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit consolidate(in_list)
# 354 ms ± 3.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit merge(in_list)
# 967 ms ± 16.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I tested the function, very good, accurate and fast, thank you. In addition I updated the simulation data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241214/merging-arrays-containing-the-same-values  If you can sync your answers, I want to end that question.

Answer (score 0):

This approach should perform faster on larger nested lists:

```
def merge(iterable):
    merged = set([tuple(set(i).union(*[j for j in a if set(i).intersection(j)])) for i in iterable])
    if merged == iterable:
        return merged
    else:
        return merge(merged)
merged(a)
#set([(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 13), (8, 9, 7)])
```

It recursively combines lists until all the combinations are exhausted.

Comment: Why would that be faster? It looks to me it has the same `O(n²)` complexity with additional overhead of the recursion.

Comment: @norok2 It does have `O(n²)` complexity however, it performs faster than originall on lager volumes - roughly 35% faster on a list 3000 times bigger (~3 mins vs ~4 mins).

Comment: I believe this could depend on the amount of intersection you have. Perhaps you can show exactly what kind of input you tested it with.

Comment: @norok2 the input was literally a * 3000 :)

Comment: Ok, but that is unlikely a meaningful input. After the first `a` is consumed, there will not be much to merge.

Comment: Thank you for your help.